# How to force the facebook android 4.x sdk to have the user re-enter their credentials?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

There are many questions & answers related to the subject, but very few specific to Facebook's Android 4.x SDK.

What I want to do is, after I call LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(), I want the user to have to re-authenticate in order to create a new AccessToken.

I am seeing that after I call LoginManager.getInstance().logOut() I am not prompted for credentials the next time I call LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(...).

Anyone know how to force LoginManager to have the user re-authenticate?

Comment: If the user has already authorized your app previously, why would you want them to re-enter their password again? Part of the point of SSO is to make the process easy for the user.

Comment: My app has a "Sign Out" action that prompts the user "OK/Cancel" dialog that also has a "Remember My Password" checkbox. If they uncheck that checkbox, then I would expect that the user would expect to be re-prompted for their Facebook credentials the next time they sign in. Why wouldn't a paranoid user not want the option to enter their FB password every time they launch the app?

Comment: I am thinking that in my case the best path here would be to hide the "Remember My Password" option if I know the user authenticated via FB.

Comment: I see your use case. I guess the differentiating factor here is that when you use FB login, you're not asking the user to supply a password for your app, but rather to supply a username/password for Facebook, which they don't need to if they're still logged into the Facebook app.

Comment: Which gets even more confusing to the user if they don't have the FB app installed! :) Thanks for your input anyway; I'll find some way to make it make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook process confused me for ages as it doesn't appear to be clearly explained, and as you point out, most of the questions are for SDK 3.

But as far as I can see the only way that the user needs to re-authenticate is if they go to

Facebook->Settings->Apps

and in App Settings click remove for the app.

If they have approved the App for login once then no matter what happens with the App on the Android device, provided that you follow the correct usage of LoginManager, it never prompts the use to re-authenticate.